# How do I take 2 columns, one for name and one for values, and spit out the unique number of amounts per unique name? Then make a list

Tags: arrays, regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-query-language

I was given a list of property names and the number of bedrooms they offer, but the info was given like this:
0 value = studio

| Property | Bedrooms |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 1 |
| Name1 | 2 |
| Name1 | 3 |
| Name2 | 0 |
| Name2 | 1 |
| Name2 | 4 |
| Name3 | 1 |
| Name3 | 2 |

I'm hoping to eventually get this information to spit out into a new sheet like so:

| Property | Bedrooms |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 1, 2, and 3 bedrooms |
| Name2 | studio, 1, and 4 bedrooms |
| Name3 | 1 and 2 bedrooms |

[image: 2nd table wouldn't show up correctly]

I can get the numbers to populate in a new cell along with the word "bedroom" by using the join function, but I'm not finding much success getting conditional values to work for things like adding a comma after the second value if there's a third.

Any help, even just linking me to the right threads, videos, etc. would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 {A2:A&"×", SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, 0, "0studio")&","}, 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where not Col1 starts with '×' 
  group by Col2
  pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")), ", (\d+),$", " and $1 bedrooms"), 
 "0studio", "studio"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

[image]

Comment: Hey Player0,

That was really close!
I didn't account for some properties only having 1 or 2 bedrooms so the output for those was "1," and "2,". Sorry about that.
Could you provide a little more assistance here?

Also, I tried to upvote you but I'm apparently too new to do so.

Comment: @Gabe so if there are only two types you dont want it to end with "bedrooms" ? or every 1 and 2 should never end with "bedrooms" ?

Comment: maybe 1 ends with "bedroom" and 2 with "bedroom"?
Do you think it reads well?

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CXvEqUyFDPWGDsDIzibJVofM5Ue3QRPj-W262rApA2Y/edit#gid=996206665